# How exactly does .then() handle the function passed in?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

According to the Promise A+ spec,

> 2.2.2.1 If onFulfilled is a function, it must be called after promise is fulfilled, with promise’s value as its first argument.

However, what happens if **a promise** is passed in .then()?

Now we have this code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var func1 = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve('hello'); 
    }); 
}

var wrapper = function() {
    return func1();
}

var api = function() {
    return wrapper()
            .then(wrapper());
}

api().then(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

**Why is 'hello' get printed?**

In the api function, wrapper() is evaluated as **a promise** through func1() and get passed in .then(). Right now, this promise acts **'onFulfilled'** function according to the spec quoted. However, the spec says the onFulfilled(the returned promise in this case) is expecting a parameter passed in as the **value** of the previous promise calling .then(). But how can the value get passed into a promise?

I am not very good at explaining things. So if you are confused, can you explain why 'hello' is printed? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how can the value get passed into a promise?

It can't and the part of the spec you quoted should have already told you that:

> If `onFulfilled` is a function [...]

a **promise is a not a function**! (usually, and if it were, it would act like a function, not like a promise).

So calling `.then` [basically doesn't do anything](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/#point-43):

> 2.2.7.3 If `onFulfilled` is not a function and `promise1` is fulfilled, `promise2` must be fulfilled with the same value as `promise1`.

`promise1` is fulfilled with `"hello"`, so that's what `promise2` to is fulfilled with as well.

```
wrapper()/*promise 1*/.then(wrapper())/*promise 2*/.then(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

is essentially

```
wrapper()/*promise 1*/.then(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

and that's why `"hello"` is printed.

---

Now, if you passed `wrapper`, a function, instead, i.e. `wrapper().then(wrapper).then(...)`, which is the same as

```
wrapper()/*a*/.then(function foo(result) {
    return func1(); /*b*/
})/*c*/.then(function(msg) {
    // ...
});
```

then `foo` would get the result from the first promise (`a`) (according to the part your quoted). And since the `onFulfilled` function returns a promise itself (`b`), the promise returned by `.then` (`c`) is resolved with value of that inner promise (`b`) (which happens to produce the same value as the first initial promise (`a`)).

This is described in [section 2.3](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/#the_promise_resolution_procedure), where `x` is the value that is returned by `onFulfilled`.

> - If x is a promise, adopt its state:
>
>   - If x is pending, promise must remain pending until x is fulfilled or rejected.
>   - If/when x is fulfilled, fulfill promise with the same value.
>   - If/when x is rejected, reject promise with the same reason.

Comment: Nice! I forgot the fact that promise is not a function.

Comment: Technically a promise _can_ be a function (with a `.then` method itself) but that's mostly discussed by obnoxious people like myself in dark #promises rooms :) Spot on answer, well written. Here's the relevant part in the code https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/promise.js#L499